# How to obtain information from 10 dates without using 10+ left joins

Tags: sql

I have some information as shown in the simplified table below.

```
login_date    | userid
-------------------------
2020-12-01    | 123
2020-12-01    | 456
2020-12-02    | 123
2020-12-02    | 456
2020-12-02    | 789
2020-12-03    | 123
2020-12-03    | 789
```

The range of dates found in `login_date` span from `2020-12-01` to `2020-12-12` and the `userid` *for each day* is unique.

What I wish to obtain comes in 2 folds:

1. The number of users who first logged in on a certain date. **excluding users who logged in on preceding day(s).**
2. For users who first logged in on a certain date (e.g. 2020-12-01), how many of them logged in on subsequent days as well? (i.e. of the batch who first logged in on 2020-12-01, how many were found to log in on 2020-12-02, 2020-12-03.. and so on)

For the above table, an example of the desired result may be as follows:

```
                                  | 2020-12-01 | 2020-12-02 | 2020-12-03 | ... (users' first login date)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     | 2020-12-01 |     2             x            x
users who continued  | 2020-12-02 |     2             1            x
to log in on these   | 2020-12-03 |     1             1            0
dates                |     ...    |
```

Reasoning:

- On the first day, two new users logged in, `123` and `456`.
- On the second day, the same *old* users, `123` and `456`, logged in as well. In addition, a new user (logging in for the first time), `789`, was added.
- On the third day, only one of the original *old* users, `123` logged in. (count of 1). The new user (from the second day), `789`, logged in as well. (count of 1)

---

**My attempt**

I actually managed to obtain a (rough) solution in two parts. For the first day, 2012-12-01, I simply filtered users who logged in on the first day and performed left joins for all the remaining dates:

```sql
select count(d1.userid) as d1_users, count(d2.userid) as d2_users, ... (repeated for all joined tables)
from table1 d1

left join (
    select userid 
    from table1
    where login_date = date('2020-12-02')
    ) d2
    on d1.userid = d2.userid

... -- (10 more left joins, with each filtering by an incremented date value)

where d1.login_date = date('2020-12-01')
```

For dates following the second day onwards, I did a bit of preprocessing to exclude users who had logged in on preceding day(s):

```sql
with d2_users as (
    select userid
    from table1 a
    
    left join (
        select userid
        from table1
        where login_date = date('2020-12-01')
        ) b
        on a.userid = b.userid

    where b.userid is null -- filtering out users who logged in on preceding day(s)
    and a.login_date = date('2020-12-02')
    )

select count(d2.userid) as d2_users, ... -- (repeated for all joined tables)
from d2_users d2

left join (
    select userid 
    from table1
    where login_date = date('2020-12-03')
    ) d3
    on d2.userid = d3.userid

... -- (similar to the query for the 2020-12-01)
```

In the process of writing and executing this query it took a lot of manual editing (deleting of unnecessary left joins for later dates and count), and ultimately the entire query for just two days takes up 300+ lines of SQL code. I am not sure whether there is a more efficient process for this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I would be happy to provide further clarification if needed as well since the optimization of the solution to this problem has been bugging me for some time.

I apologize for the poor formatting of the desired result, as I currently only have a representation of it in a spreadsheet and not an idea of how it may look like as a SQL output.

---

Edit:

I realized I may not have communicated the ideal outcomes properly. For each min_login_date identified, what I wish to obtain is the number of users who *continue* to log in from a preceding date. An example would be:

- 10 users log in on 2020-12-01. Hence, the count for 2020-12-01 = 10.
- Of the 10 previous users, 8 users log in on 2020-12-02. Hence the count for 2020-12-02 = 8.
- Of the **8 users (from the previous day)**, 6 users log in on 2020-12-03. Hence the count for 2020-12-03 = 6.

As such for each min_login_date, the user count for subsequent dates should be <= that of the user count for previous dates. Hope this helps! I apologize for any miscommunication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to get the earliest date.  And then aggregate:

```
select min_login_date, count(*) as num_on_day,
       sum(case when login_date = '2020-12-01' then 1 else 0 end) as login_20201201,
       sum(case when login_date = '2020-12-02' then 1 else 0 end) as login_20201203,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             min(login_date) over (partition by user_id) as min_login_date
      from t
     ) t
group by min_login_date
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the answer. The query runs perfectly fine. However, your answer made me realize that I may have not represented my desired outcomes as ideally as possible. What I was actually looking for is:


For instance, 10 users log in on 2020-12-01. Of these 10 users, 8 of them continue to log in on 2020-12-02. Then, of these **8 users**, 6 of them continue to log in on 2020-12-03.

The above example is actually the 'actual' count which I am looking for. So the actual data for each min_login_date should actually be decrementing over the subsequent dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some tweak using analytical function and aggregate function as follows:

```
select login_date,
       Count(case when min_login_date = '2020-12-01' then 1 end) as login_20201201,
       Count(case when min_login_date = '2020-12-02' then 1 end) as login_20201202,
       ......
 from (select t.*,
              min(login_date) over (partition by user_id) as min_login_date,
              Lag(login_date) over (partition by user_id) as lag_login_date,
         from your_taeble t 
        Where t.login_date between '2020-12-01'  and '2020-12-12' 
      ) t 
where (lag_login_date = login_date - interval '1 day' or lag_login_date is null)
group by login_date
```